# Calculate sum based on another data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, date

First data frame (`df`):

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 6:15:00 | 6:15:06 |
| 6:15:00 | 6:15:00 |
| 6:15:00 | 6:15:01 |
| 6:15:01 | 6:15:06 |
| 6:15:01 | 6:15:15 |
| 6:15:01 | 6:15:09 |
| 6:15:01 | 6:15:09 |
| 6:15:02 | 6:15:06 |
| 6:15:02 | 6:15:08 |
| 6:15:02 | 6:15:09 |

`df2`:

| periods (1 sec timedelta) | total |
| --- | --- |
| 6:15:00 | 2 |
| 6:15:01 | 5 |
| 6:15:02 | 8 |

How to calculate total in `df2` without using loops? For each period in `df2` sum of rows from `df` is needed, provided that `start <= period` and `end >= period (total)`. For example `6:15:02` in `df2 = x`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


x = datetime(year=2023,month=10, day=6, hour=6, minute=15, second=2).time()

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['6:15:00', '6:15:00', '6:15:00', '6:15:01', '6:15:01', '6:15:01', '6:15:01', '6:15:02', '6:15:02', '6:15:02'],
              'end': ['6:15:06', '6:15:00', '6:15:01', '6:15:06', '6:15:15', '6:15:09', '6:15:09', '6:15:06', '6:15:08', '6:15:09']})

df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], yearfirst=True).dt.time
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], yearfirst=True).dt.time

start = datetime(year=2023,month=10, day=6, hour=6, minute=15, second=0)
end = datetime(year=2023,month=10, day=6, hour=6, minute=15, second=2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"periods (1 sec timedelta)": pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq=timedelta(seconds=1)), "total": None})
df2["periods (1 sec timedelta)"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["periods (1 sec timedelta)"], yearfirst=True).dt.time

total = len(df[(df['start'] <= x) & (df['end'] >= x)])
```

`total` = 8. If counted for each row in `df2` it takes a lot of time. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: you can use the `apply ` method along with lambda functions to calculate the total for each period in DF2.

Comment: attach a year to your `df` frame - it does not make sense to compare time values with datetime

Comment: how can you do without apply for speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the time like columns to `timedelta` array, then call a function which will return the count of rows satisfying the given condition. The trick here is to compile the function with `numba` to achive C like speeds and since your dataframes are big numba would be the ideal approach for efficiency and memory management

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(period, start, end):
    for p in period:
        mask = (start <= p) & (end >= p)
        yield sum(mask)


def to_timedelta_arr(col):
    return pd.to_timedelta(col.astype(str)).to_numpy()


df2['total'] = list(func(to_timedelta_arr(df2['periods (1 sec timedelta)']),
                         to_timedelta_arr(df['start']), to_timedelta_arr(df['end'])))
```

---

```
  periods (1 sec timedelta)  total
0                  06:15:00      3
1                  06:15:01      6
2                  06:15:02      8
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this should do the work:

```
def calculate_total(period):
    return len(df1[(df1['start'] <= period) & (df1['end'] >= period)])

df2['total'] = df2['periods (1 sec timedelta)'].apply(calculate_total)
```

The `calculate_total`  function will calculate rows in df1

- where the `start time` is less than or equal to the `input period` and the `end time` is greater than or equal to the input period.

Then, this function is applied to each row of `df2['periods (1 sec timedelta)']` to compute and assign the `'total' column` in df2.

Comment: thanks, it works, but it's loops. Real volumes of dataframes are ~100k rows. I think , how  use merge, group by, sum and np.where, but I haven’t figured out how to do it yet